# Can I use automatic google export of Google Analytics Premium data to more than 1 BigQuery projects?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I was wondering if it is possible to have google automatically export google analytics premium data to more than one bigquery projects?

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 1):

There is no such possibility. You can share the dataset with relevant people if you want to extend beyond the current scope, but you cannot have it in multiple projects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is that also written somewhere is google documentation? The thing is that I'm in this scenario: I'm asked to analyze GA premium data in my own bigquery project, but (1) I don't want to use the monthly $500 coupon that is for GA premium owner but it's obligatory for exporting GA data to BQ and (2) I don't want to prevent the GA owner having its own GA-BQ connection.

Comment: It sounds like you want the GA account holder to export the data to their own project and share the dataset with you, and then you can analyze it from your own project.